# Translucency with fixed-function OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to render an aquarium and for that I need a translucent cuboid.  What am I doing wrong?

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT); 
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);  
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,myCubeVertices); //the cuboid model is under myCube
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,myCubeColors); //just blue

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);   
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,myCubeVertexCount);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

This is how it looks like right now:
[image: aquarium]

Answer (score 0):

```
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,myCubeColors); //just blue
```

This is where you went wrong. myCubeColors needs to be RGBA format, with the A denoting the alpha or transparancy with 0.0 being fully transparent.

So it would look like:

```
glColorPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,0,myCubeColors); //just blue
```

You will also need appropriate changes to any shaders you are using if they are expecting RGB format (aka a vec3 instead of a vec4).

Hope that helps.